# Three pairwise uncorrelated random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, correlation

Given $\xi$, $\eta$, $\zeta$ are pairwise uncorrelated, can we say, that $E(\xi\eta\zeta) = E\xi E\eta E\zeta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Counterexample:

Let $\xi$ and $\eta$ be iid with $\mathbb{P}\left(\xi=1\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\xi=-1\right)=\frac{1}{2}$
and let $\zeta:=\xi\eta$.

Then $\xi$, $\eta$ and $\zeta$ are pairwise uncorrelated.

However $\mathbb{E}\xi\zeta\eta=\mathbb{E}\xi^2\eta^2=1\neq0=\mathbb{E}\xi\mathbb{E}\zeta\mathbb{E}\eta$.

Comment: $\mathbb P(\xi\in\{-1,1\})=1$ and $\{\xi\in\{-1,1\}\}=\{\xi^2=1\}$. So in fact $\xi^2=1$ a.s. Likewise $\eta^2=1$ a.s.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I am just dumb. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Very welcome and glad to help.